# PHP MySql - Maximum number of queries in each page load

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My application has an average of 2000 online users, which is a very high number of page loads. My question is how many mysql queries I can do in each page load ?
because my application requires loading lot of data.

Is it possible that my database crashes? or my server?

***_*____ SOME INFO *_*____**
Memory Limit: 60Mb
Parallel Processes: 15
Script executing time: 30 seg
DB: MySQL5 (1Gb)

Structure: in the structure, all the tables are really well interconnected. Allmowst the 95% of the fields are INT type (related by FOREIGN and PRIMARY keys).
There are 14 tables. In total, there are 32 INT fields, and 6 TEXT ones.

What if I can't install applications ON my server, is there any other way to cache my data?

Comment: It depends on your server whether your app crashes or not. You need to give more detail about your setup.

Comment: 2000 concurrent users accessing my laptop will cause it to crash. 200 concurrent users hitting a solid server will barely make a dent in the performance. You really need to post more information.

Comment: Ok, sorry... I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such load, you should probably start thinking about setting up some sort of cache - so request will hit DB only once.

My choice for this would be [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

In case if you have partially dynamic content, which for example is user-related data, you can use it with [**Edge Side Includes**](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/esi.html).

Also, try to optimize your queries to as less as possible by aggregating select conditions. For example, first - collect all `ids` you need to select, then - do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (...)`

After that - you will be able to work with result on server side, without bothering database

---

**EDIT**

If you are unable to install any applications on your hosting - then you should proceed with fetching as much data as possible with one request, and then - work with arrays.

And also **it is important** to have indexed fields - this will speed up your queries.

Comment: As I can't install software on my server, I will consider the second option. And... what I pointed out in my updated answer... does this kind of Db structure work faster?. Thank you a lot for these tips :D

Answer (score 1):

For such load you might want to set up [multiple servers with replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html) and with load balancer between application and MySQL server to distribute read load among multiple instances (and consider caching and optimising your queries, as suggested by @thecatontheflat). It'd also help availability (when one DB server is down, others might take it's share of work)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but... so far, this isn't possible for me. However, I will consider it later. Thanks!